# Trying to improve a vegetarian wrap by adding spinach

Tags: sandwich, spinach, tortilla

I am trying to come up with a recipe for a wrap (in a tortilla) and my idea features slightly fried vegetables and spring onion, sour cream, spinach and mozzarella.
I would usually try out different approaches and come up with a recipe through trial and error, but this time I don't have this luxury and yet I want my wrap to be tasty and well balanced.

The current plan is to slightly fry the vegetables in a pan with the lid on. After that, while still hot, I plan on adding the sour cream and mixing it up. The mozzarella is added inside at the end so it melts while the wrap is in a closed toaster or on a grill.

The main idea is super simple and actually my only concern is about the spinach. I don't want it to dominate in the dish, but still give that hint in the wrap. I don't have any specific amounts for the the other products.

What suggestions would you give me for the preparation of the spinach and how much should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fresh uncooked washed baby spinach would be best. Just the leaves, no stems.

If you wanted to, you could lay the spinach out over the wrap, then put the fried ingredients on while hot, so that they partially cook the spinach, add your sauce, then roll up.